# What is the barest bare-boned operating system available?

Tags: operating-system

What are some tiny open source operating systems? I'm looking for something several orders of magnitude smaller than Puppy Linux, Feather Linux, DSL, etc. I want to run a command-line text editor and compiler; anything else is extraneous. I'm looking for a system I can take apart and acquire a fairly good understanding of the whole thing in a reasonable period of time.  Bonus points for something that is portable and well-documented.

Comment: Able to extrapolate on what you want it for? I'm interested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are also completely different research/teaching operating systems around, like [**TOPSY**](http://www.topsy.net/).

> Topsy is a small footprint native
>   multi-threading, multi-tasking
>   operating system based on a
>   micro-kernel architecture with a
>   message passing communication
>   infrastructure.

ANSI C, ~20k lines. It was apparently ported to ia32, MIPS R3000/R4000, StrongARM SA110, Intel IXP1200, Intel IXP2400 and Motorola 68K. You'll find various thesis reports on their website.

Comment: Alternative Link to TOPSY: http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/~topsy/

Answer (score 18):

If you're trying to understand the kernel, look at Minix.  The Linux kernel is too big for an academic exercise.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with using Minix. You get gcc, vi, emacs, bash. flex. bison, man and TEX if you install the whole thing, but you can cut it off to just kernel, bash, gcc and vi

Answer (score 2):

There once was "PeeWeeLinux" -- It was a bunch of shell scripts running on Red Hat 6.2.  You could build the system (pick and choose) from a series of menus, once you figured it out.  It's four years old now.  I built a 4MB system: 1/2MB for Linux plus 3.5 for PHP!

And then there was a guy who built a comm terminal app, by taking the Linux kernel and replacing *init* with his application!

You should say *which* editor and *which* compiler.  Busybox in 100K gives you a limited vi, for example.  But I think if you want gcc, *that* will determine the size of the target system.

Answer (score 2):

Try [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html). It's based on Sixth Edition Unix (aka V6). You can run it `qemu`/`bochs`. Use `gdb` to see code from boot itself.
It's used by many university for academic purpose. Good Documentation.
Here is the [MIT's 6.828 Operating System Engineering course](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/overview.html) based on xv6 since 2002. The book is split into chapters, each will help you understand the some part of operating system like file system or process management and also explains the xv6 source code side by side, so you don't have to just scan the code to understand by yourself.
The book is really small ~80 pages: [xv6 book pdf](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6/xv6-rev7.pdf). You can obtain it's sources via `git(1)`: `$ git clone git://pdos.csail.mit.edu/xv6/xv6.git`
You can also do lot of simple assignment given in some university.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Make your own distro with only the pieces you need.

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: Comprehensive, but probably wouldn't fit the "reasonable time period" constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Xinu - Xinu Is Not Unix - by Douglas Comer.  It was originally on LSI (PDP-11) machines, but has been ported to a number of other architectures.  You can find more information and the source at [Purdue University](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/research/xinu.html).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what compiler. [JX](http://www4.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Projects/JX/) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely FOSS but you might look at QNX (aka Qnix).  It is micro-kernel OS targeted at embedded systems.

I have no affiliation... [See wiki link here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNX)  Note that the source was made available awhile back.

Answer (score 1):

**Not Another Completely Heuristic Operating System (NACHOS)**
[NACHOS wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Another_Completely_Heuristic_Operating_System)

[cs.washington.edu](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/tom/nachos/)

Answer (score 1):

[Contiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiki) is very small. Perhaps too small for your needs and/or hardware target, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go hard-core, there is "bare metal" from return infinity.
http://www.returninfinity.com/baremetal.html

Comment: Great find - I've done a lot of HPC, but I believe it deserves a closer look! Are you by any chance affiliated with them? We should chat, especially about GAMMA and low-latency message passing.

Comment: I am not affiliated with them at all, just stumbled accross their site a while back and have been following them on twitter for status updates.

Answer (score 0):

[tomsrtbt](http://www.toms.net/rb/): "The most GNU/Linux on 1 floppy disk."

Comment: What's a floppy disk? And where did I put my mirrored shades? :)

Comment: I think I saw them in that box with the dialup modems :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree on Minix. Also the book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Operating-Systems-Implementation-Prentice-Software/dp/0131429388](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131429388)

is actually fairly comprehensible. (Unlike some books on similar topics, thinking of "Understanding the Linux kernel" here.) It's quite expensive, but you can probably pick up an earlier edition second-hand.

(NB. I'm not in any way affiliated with the book, it's just good :) )

Answer (score 0):

OpenBSD could be a good choice, I think the default install (no X11) has something like 15 processes. FreeBSD is a close second. Either way you'll want to read "[The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201702452)"

BTW, I've spent a considerable amount of time on AIX, Solaris, FreeBSD, and Linux... and I think the OpenBSD man pages are the best around.

Answer (score 0):

I still fondly remember XINU (XINU is not UNIX) from college.
Not sure it would provide everything you need,
but it was fairly educational when I was in college, and easily fit on a floppy along with a turbo C :)

Answer (score 0):

> a system I can take apart

Also have a look at the Bootdisk Howto, to find out what it is you are about to take apart.